# Documentation of method

Tags: java, documentation

I would like to know the best practice for documentating the following method that simplifies a rational number.

```
/**
 * Simplifies a rational number
 * 
 * @return  ...
 *          | result == new Rational(this.getNumerator() / gcd, this.getDenominator()/ gcd);
 */
public Rational simplify() {
    long gcd = ExtMath.gcd(Math.abs(this.getNumerator()),
            Math.abs(this.getDenominator()));
    if (this.getDenominator() < 0)
        gcd *= -1;
    return new Rational(this.getNumerator() / gcd, this.getDenominator()
            / gcd);
}
```

Comment: What kind of best practice you're looking for?

Comment: Do you mean how to write the Javadoc? Or are you asking about what should go into the Javadoc? Or are you asking if writing Javadoc comments is the best practice? (It is.)

Comment: @TedHopp I wonder what should go into the Javadoc.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Things like "@pre", "@post", "@effect", "@return". My problem is that I don't have a fully understanding of these notations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc should start with a relatively short sentence that states what the method does. (This sentence gets extracted into the method summary for the class documentation.) It can then elaborate if needed for clarity. However, you should not describe the internal operation of the method unless that is important for understanding how to write client code for using the method. The Javadoc should also include an `@return` tag documenting the return value.

Assuming that the method is part of the `Rational` class, I'd probably write something like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a new {@code Rational} that represents this {@code Rational} in reduced
 * form. The denominator of the returned value will be non-negative.
 *
 * @return a new {@code Rational} that represents this {@code Rational}
 *         in reduced form.
 */
```

If it's possible for an exception to be thrown for special values of a `Rational` (e.g., a zero denominator), then I'd probably add a `@throws` tag documenting when that will happen.

If this method is closely related to something else, I might also add one or more `@see` tags.

P.S. Tags like `@pre`, `@post`, etc., are custom tags (see [the docs here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#annotations)). There are lots of guides for how to use these (see [here](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/205/Resources/customtags.html), for example), but I'm not aware of any "best practices" other than to be clear.

Comment: Thanks but I actually want to describe the internal operation and I don't know what's the clean way of doing that.

Comment: @Michiel - Generally that's done through normal Java comments inside the method. If you want to make the internal operation part of the public contract (usually not recommended), then simply add a paragraph to the Javadoc explaining the relevant parts of how it works. In extreme cases, you can simply repeat the body of the method in the comments, including a short introduction like "Internally the method works as follows:" (or something to that effect).

Comment: @Michiel just to add to the great explanation by Ted Hopp, you can take as example [`java.util.Random#nextXyz`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) methods.